# Cloned android partition is corrupted on Windows

Tags: adb

I'm trying to clone the partition containing /data on to my Windows machine, but whenever I use adb pull and try mounting it, I get an error saying the disk image files is corrupted. Do I need to do something to the file to make it mountable for Windows?

The partition /data is located on is called /dev/block/dm-30. So far I have tried: `adb pull -a /dev/block/dm-30 C:/Users/user/source` and I have also tried using in adb shell: `dd if=/dev/block/dm-30 of=/sdcard/Documents/part.img` and I tried pulling that image file as well and they both resulted in being corrupted when I tried using it on Windows.

Comment: Is your device rooted? And if it is do you use an adb versions that has root permissions, because otherwise adb pull is useless. Also keep in mind that on devices released the last years `/data` is encrypted, and can only be decrypted on-device as it is bound to the key in TEE.